# Cant read RFID card consistently from EM18 + Raspberrypi

Tags: raspberry-pi3, rfid

I connected ***EM18*** rfid reader to ***RaspberryPi***. Cards get read sometimes and sometimes not. In other words it is not read in a single attempt every time. Though after a successful read output is correct but the reading is not guaranteed flawlessly in every attempt.
***But if I use NodeMCU in place of RaspberryPi reading is flawlessly fast and consistent.***
My python code is :

```
import serial                                #import serial module

def read_rfid ():
   ser = serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyAMA0")      #Open named port 
   ser.baudrate = 9600                       #Set baud rate to 9600
   data = ser.read(12)                       #Read 12 characters from serial port to data
   ser.close ()                              #Close port
   return data                               #Return data

id = read_rfid ()                            #Function call
print id
```

***Hardware details :***

raspberrypi 3B+ (buster OS)
EM18 sensor (not module)
Tx pin of em18 is connected to raspberrpi's Rx ( Serial is enabled on raspberrypi)

Comment: more appropriate https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not robust enough. You have to see it this way to explain why you only get the RFID tag sometimes: when you run your code, Python's interpreter goes line by line, first, it instantiates the port. That's going to take maybe a couple of seconds, then you change the baud rate and afterward you try to read 12 bytes from the port. If you present the card exactly at the same time your code is waiting to get data it will return successfully. But you have some delay on the card reader as well, so in practice, it will be quite difficult to keep those two operations (running you code and knowing when it will be waiting for data and presenting the card to the reader) in sync.

To avoid that you can just add a loop that waits until data arrives to the port. Something like this should work:

```
import serial                                                     #import serial module
import time

def read_rfid ():
   ser = serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyAMA0")                           #Open named port 
   time.sleep(1)                                                  #Wait a bit to make sure serial port is instantiated correctly
   ser.baudrate = 9600                                            #Set baud rate to 9600
   data = ''
   while ser.inWaiting() == 0 and len(data)<12:
       data = data + ser.read()                                                       #Just wait until data is received

   ser.close ()                                                   #Close port
   return data                                                    #Return data

id = read_rfid ()                                              #Function call
print id
```

Comment: Thankyou Marcos for your help <3 its working better but still inconsistent and not that flawless as like with NodeMCU :(

Comment: I don't have any RFID reader to debug further. Maybe you can show the nodeMCU code to compare?

Comment: thanx for reply :) .... I have taken my code from 
https://electrosome.com/em-18-rfid-reader-arduino-uno/

Comment: You can try to replicate the conditions on the loop to wait for exactly 12 bytes. See edit

Comment: Might be a hardware issue then. Have you tried connecting the GND on the RPi to GND on the RFID module?

Comment: Another thing that comes to mind: have you disabled the kernel console messages on the RPi?

Comment: when I use RFID reader with raspberrypi, It is totally powered from raspberrypi only. So ground will be connected to raspberrypi only.
and yes I have disabled console and enabled Serial.

Comment: And what about the supply voltage? Is it 3.3 or 5 V? I don't see any other obvious reason for your code to work unreliably

Comment: Supply voltage is 5V (from Pi's pin). This issue is strange for me too. But this is happening :(

Comment: The UART on the RPi works with 3.3 V levels but the TX on your RFID module seems to be using 5 V. That might be a problem, you might need a voltage divider to reduce the voltage a bit.

Comment: That's actually explained in the tutorials you are following, right?

Comment: I have not connected the two capacitors shown in the circuit diagram of the tutorial. And connected directly to the raspberrypi with voltage divider only. Is that the reason for inconsistency ?

Comment: decoupling capacitors are good practice, it might be a good idea to add them, in particular when something is not working as expected. You can take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcJ6UdDx1vg), the problem is complex with a lot of nuances. I would also measure the voltage you are getting out of the RFID module UART, if you have access to an oscilloscope. Or if you don't, double-check the values of the resistances on the divider and measure them with a multimeter to make sure they are within tolerance

Comment: I have now connected 100uF capacitor but didnt connect 0.1uF capacitor as it was not available at this time. It works many times better than before :)  but still not as good as with Nodemcu. Is the problem that I have not connected 0.1uF capacitor ??? Do I need to connect 0.1uF capacitor also  to get desired result ?

Comment: It could be, have you watched the video I linked above? Sometimes you need different values to bypass different frequencies. I would not be surprised if you are picking up noise on the RFID frequency. As I said, noise is much easier to detect and cure if you have a scope

Comment: I got to know that why it was not working ... 1. capacitors were not included. 2. power issue.
I am using raspberrpi and now em18 module and when i connect both then em18 module starts to show inconsistency and its reading range also decreases significantly. When em18 module is alone run then it reads card very flawlessly and its range is also very good. I am powering it(raspberrypi and em18 module) with 5v 2.7 Amps phone charger. Am i correct that the current is insufficient or anything else . Can you suggest some solution ?

Comment: The power supply for the Pi is tricky indeed. You should try to avoid most cheap phone chargers, no matter their rating. I have several chargers that work fine but I've had more than one headache with others, even if they are supposed to give 3 or more amps they won't keep the voltage constant (as you probably know there is a safety system on the Pi that switches it off if it detects the power supply voltage changing too much). Conclusion: just try to get a good power supply.

Comment: And if I want to use battery pack (LiPo 18650 of 4 cells) then can I use two boost converters (2 Amps each) separately to power EM18 module and raspberrypi from same pack. Will this trick work (in case if I want to operate on battery only).

Comment: It depends on the quality of the converters. It might be worth trying.

Comment: Thanx bro for your help :)  Things are working well now.